# Historical data structure on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Based on a certain time interval I need to implement pre-aggregated statistical data based on the following model:

I have a `Product` entity and `ProductGroup` entity that plays a role of Products container. I can have 0..N Products and 0..N ProductGroups with the `MANY_2_MANY` relationship between Products and ProductGroups.

Based on some own business logic I can calculate the order of every Product in the every ProductGroup.

I will do this calculation continuously per some period of time... let's say via Cron job.

I also would like to store the history for every calculation(versions) in order to be able to analyze the `Product` positions shifts.

I have created a simple picture with this structure:

[image]

Right now I use MongoDB database and really interested to implement this structure on MongoDB without introducing new technologies.

My functional requirements - I need to have the ability to quickly get the position(and position offset) for certain `Product` in the certain `ProductGroup`. Let's say `P2` position and offset for `ProductGroup1`. The output should be:

```
position: 1
offset  : +2
```

Also, I'd like to visualize the graphics and show the historical changes of positions for a certain Product with a certain ProductGroup. For example for Product `P2` in ProductGroup1 the output should be:

```
1(+2), 3(-3), 0
```

Is it possible to implement with MongoDB and if so, could you please describe the MongoDB collection(s) structure in order to support this?

Comment: Could you elaborate meaning of 2 identical images? I believe it makes perfect sense to you, but it's not quite clear why you repeat the chain twice when you have only information provided in the question.

Comment: I apologize, this is just a copy paste to show that there are 0..N ProductGroups in system. For sure the statistic data will differ between these groups

Comment: But it is the same Product Group 1, innit?

Comment: Please read the second group as ProductGroup2. I’ll fix the image from my computer soon

Comment: @AlexBlex I have updated the image

Comment: Cool, makes more sense now. Could you confirm a product can have multiple positions within a group, or it is a copy&paste as well, and should be read as something different?

Comment: At one certain period of time, one Product can hold only a single position within a group. Different rectangles in the picture represent snapshots of the product group(with the products positions and position offsets inside of this group) in different periods of time. Let's say - now, yesterday, the day before yesterday and so on and so forth.

Comment: Fair enough, so what should be in the version 2 box of group 1? There are 2 P4s atm.

Comment: Also, could you highlight if there are any constraints that stops you using a naïve approach with a "snapshot" collection that holds all the "boxes"?

Comment: This is one more typo with P4, sorry. Regarding the approach with the “snapshot” collection - I’m okay with this if it will allow me to quickly query the data as I described at my question

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The math in version 1 of group 1 is wrong, but that's okay. Versions are counted other way round, but again we can chalk it as one more typo of rather [BFG style](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/222781) description. The most interesting question is what you expect asking for P6 position in group1? It is not in the latest version, so is it an empty result or position 4, offset 0 from version 2?

Comment: It should be an empty result this case. This case says that the product is no longer exists in this ProducGroup1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only limitation is to "quickly query the data as I described at my question", the simplest way is to have a collection of snapshots with an array of products:

```
db.snapshots.insert({
    group: "group 1", 
    products:[
        {id:"P2", position:0, offset:0},
        {id:"P4", position:1, offset:0},
        {id:"P5", position:2, offset:0},
        {id:"P6", position:3, offset:0}
    ], ver:0
});

db.snapshots.insert({
    group: "group 1", 
    products:[
        {id:"P3", position:0, offset:0},
        {id:"P5", position:1, offset:1},
        {id:"P1", position:2, offset:0},
        {id:"P2", position:3, offset:-3},
        {id:"P4", position:4, offset:0}
    ], ver:1
});
```

The index would be

```
db.snapshots.createIndex(
    { group: 1, ver: -1,  "products.id": 1 }, 
    { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "products.id": { $exists: true } } } 
);
```

And the query to fetch current position of a product in the group ("P4" in "group 1" in the example):

```
db.snapshots.find(
    { group: "group 1" }, 
    { _id: 0, products: { $elemMatch: { id: "P4" } } }
).sort( { ver:-1 } ).limit(1)
```

A query to fetch historical data is almost the same:

```
db.snapshots.find(
    { group: "group 1" }, 
    { _id: 0, products: { $elemMatch: {id: "P4" } }, ver: 1 }
).sort({ver:-1})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this approach